# Toggle between two DIVs with two buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to toggle between two div in the same section with two different buttons that every div connect to one button.

Example: (I need that whenever 'btn1' is ACTIVE 'div1' is VISIBLE. And when I click on 'btn2', 'div2' is VISIBLE instead of 'div1' and vice versa! help ?

```css
* {
  color: #fff;
  }
.btn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  display: inline-block;
  }
.btn-active {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  }
.div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: none;
  }
.div-active {
  display: block;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="btn btn-active" id="btn1">
    BUTTON 1
  </div>
  <div class="btn" id="btn2">
    BUTTON 2
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="div div-active" id="div1">
    DIV 1
  </div>
  <div class="div" id="div2">
  DIV 2 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you attempted to solve this?  You didn't include any of your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is to first group all of your buttons and divs into two collections. From here, I would add an event listener to each of the buttons. This listener would first remove **all** `div-active` classes, and then re-apply the `div.active` class to the corresponding div.

This can be seen in the following example:

```js
const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
const divs = document.getElementsByClassName('div');

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      divs[i].classList.remove('div-active');
    }
    divs[i].classList.add('div-active');
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  color: #fff;
}

.btn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn-active {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: none;
}

.div-active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="btn btn-active" id="btn1">
    BUTTON 1
  </div>
  <div class="btn" id="btn2">
    BUTTON 2
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="div div-active" id="div1">
    DIV 1
  </div>
  <div class="div" id="div2">
    DIV 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<div>
    <div class="btn btn-active" id="btn1">
        BUTTON 1
    </div>
    <div class="btn" id="btn2">
        BUTTON 2
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="div " id="div1">
        DIV 1
    </div>
    <div class="div div-active" id="div2">
        DIV 2   
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
    var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
    var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
    var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
    //
    btn1.addEventListener("click", function(){
        btn1.classList.remove("btn-active");
        btn2.classList.add("btn-active");            
        div2.classList.remove("div-active");
        div1.classList.add("div-active");
    });
    //
    btn2.addEventListener("click", function(){
        btn2.classList.remove("btn-active");
        btn1.classList.add("btn-active");            
        div1.classList.remove("div-active");
        div2.classList.add("div-active");            
    });        
</script>
```